# Is there an accessible callback when Craft.EntryTypeSwitcher is run?

Tags: plugins, javascript, garnish

When a user switches Entry Types in the control panel, `Craft.EntryTypeSwitcher` is trigged which in turn triggers `onTypeChange`.

Is there callback that a plugin can access to run some additional JavaScript after this event has occurred?

===== Edit to show Current work-around as per Justin's answer below ======

```javscript
(function($) {
    Craft.LoadOverride = Garnish.Base.extend({
        init: function()
        {
            this.addListener(Garnish.$win, 'resize', 'runOverride');
        },
        runOverride: function()
        {
            console.log('Triggered!');
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the only easy way to hook into that event is to listen for the `resize` event on the `window` object. On line 55, it is triggering `resize()`. Looking at the code, I am not seeing any other way to listen for these events. The `Craft.EntryTypeSwitcher` class is getting instantiated but not getting assigned to any variable in the DOM, so there is no way for you to grab that instance (from what I can tell anyway).

Comment: Hi Justin, thanks for the answer. That was kind of what I was seeing as well. Listening for the `resize` might be ok temporarily, but I'm really only looking for this code to be executed at the end of this specific event. Feature Request! :-)

Comment: Just a note on this: I was able to get this working by listening for the `resize` event as Justin has described. I'm going to wait a short time to see if P&T weigh in on this as it would be nice to access the instance directly. Otherwise, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Exactly my thoughts on the topic. Glad you got that working for now at least.

Answer (score 3):

The most reliable way I've found to listen for the entry type switching would be to add an `ajaxComplete` listener to the `document` object, testing the call's URL for the `switchEntryType` action handle:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(myAjaxCompleteHandler);

function myAjaxCompleteHandler( e, status, requestData )
{
    if ( requestData.url.indexOf( 'switchEntryType' ) > -1 ) {
        // Entry type switched. Do your stuff!
        ...
    }
}
```

If you need the new/active entry type's ID after the switch, the easiest way to get that would be by getting the entry type dropdown's value:

```
var entryTypeId = $( '#entryType' ).val();
```

Other data, like all the fields and the section ID, is available as part of the `requestData` object, specifically as a serialized string under `requestData.data`. Here's a very basic deserialization to get to the entry type and section IDs:

```
var data = {},
    params = $.map( unescape( requestData.data ).split( '&' ), function ( param ) {
        param = param.split( '=' );
        data[ param[ 0 ] ] = param[ 1 ] || null;
    } ),
    sectionId = parseInt( data.sectionId ),
    entryTypeId = parseInt( data.typeId );

}
```

The field data is more complex – many fields will be *arrays* which aren't handled well by the above example – but there's several jQuery plugins to help out with that stuff if you need it :)